# HTML textbox not inline

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I acurrently have two input controls on the same line however they do not seem to align properly with the other controls above it and it looks rather off.  I am not sure how to get them to align properly.  Here is what the modal currently looks like: http://gyazo.com/4060e39e20391f1e9561e654dc64f9bb  It's almost there but not quite there yet.  Here is the HTML that I have writtem

```
<div id="modalContent">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="datapointName">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="Name" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="tName" data-val-required="Name field is required" data-val="true">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Desc">Description:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <textarea id="Desc" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="Desc" data-val="false"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="code">code:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="code" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="datapointOID" data-val-required="Code is a required field" data-val="true">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="metricType"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select id="metricType" class="form-control" name="metricType" data-val="false"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="valueMin">Value Range:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="valueMin" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="valueMin" data-val="false">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p>-</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="valueMax" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="valueMax" data-val="false">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-default btn-ok" id="savedp">Save</button>
</div>
```

and here is my css that was auto generated when created my MVC project in visual studio

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Bootstrap's rules correctly? Or is some other CSS interfering with your form's styles? - http://jsfiddle.net/cpyyn9rr/ This is how it looks just using Bootstrap, which is alot nicer than your example.

Comment: @Lee  the only css that has an effect on this is one originally generated when I started up an MVC project in visual studio.  Which I will amend my post in order to accommodate this as well.

Comment: Try using a combination of Bootstrap's inline form within the one you've done, and that should sort it.

Comment: So I should wrap it in an inline form then?

Comment: Just the two fields you want side by side, wrap them in a div and give it the class form-inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to use rows when making columns.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
 <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
 <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

I have fixed your code in a pen.

http://codepen.io/costh/pen/XbzGxL

Comment: This almost worked! however the value boxes go outside the modal and so do the buttons at the bottom.  Here is a screenshot http://gyazo.com/edbbc9088893203cf5c14cc3c2a727a4

Comment: I changed container to container-fluid

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your columns are a bit confused...

Try this :

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="modalContent">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="datapointName">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="Name" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="tName" data-val-required="Name field is required" data-val="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Desc">Description:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <textarea id="Desc" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="Desc" data-val="false"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="code">code:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="code" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="datapointOID" data-val-required="Code is a required field" data-val="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /input-group -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="metricType"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="metricType" class="form-control" name="metricType" data-val="false"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /input-group -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="valueMin">Value Range:</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                    <div class="col-md-5" style="padding-left:0px;">
                        <input id="valueMin" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="valueMin" data-val="false" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <p style="text-align:center;">-</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5" style="padding-right:0px;">
                        <input id="valueMax" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="valueMax" data-val="false" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /input-group -->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-default btn-ok" id="savedp">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please excuse the in-line styles!

Comment: I have tried this suggestion but the bootstrap modal seems to not show.

Comment: In your initial code your `<div id="modalContent">` was missing its closing tag. In my code, I closed this off for you. You might want to double check that that isn't causing your issue. So try removing the last `</div>` tag from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
   <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="valuerang">
       <span class="input-group-addon">Value Range:</span>
        <input class="input-sm form-control" name="start" type="text" id="abc"  required> <span class="input-group-addon"> - </span>
        <input class="input-sm form-control" name="end" type="text" id="abc" required> 
  </div>
</div>
```

make sure you modify the tag names to suit your application.

Comment: I don't think you need to put each input in a seperate form-group too.